# jquery autocomplete additional data

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

im using this autocomplete with codeigniter tutorial

http://www.codersmount.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database/
and got it working on my test site, but i wanted to attach additional data into it
which will be pointed to a hidden text field.  what i did was echo out the additional data
and then explode it before processing the data, but the problem is that i dont want the additional data to be displayed when using the autocomplete.
can anyone help me with this?

here is the jquery code:

```
$("#member").autocomplete({
source: "<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/get_member');?>"
});
```

pls. help guys.. thanks u in advance.

Comment: Is it a valid JSON format?? Anyway, I don't think you can just echo the JSON via absolute URL. Why don't you just pass that info throughout the view? `$this->load->view('someview',$jsonData);`

Comment: not sure which end you want additional data added to... sending term to server with additional data, or adding extra data in json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not too sure about the latest JqueryUI autocomplete, but the last version did not allow for extra parameters in the URL, what you had to do is create a function to add the extra params to your url.

have a look at the api and it will show you how to do it.